# look for a way to return DeliverSmResp with error codes from cloudhopper smpp server

Tags: java, smpp

i am looking for a way to send SMPP error codes from the server to the connected client.
my Flow is :
1. client send to my Server text message
2. i send it to another system
3. when i got status of messages (can take up to 72 hours)
i want to send the results back to the client that is connected as a Receiver.
also i noticed when i send it to the client i see :

> Default handling is to discard unexpected response PDU: (submit_sm_resp:

```
public void sendResponsePdu(String dlrId, String status) throws RecoverablePduException, SmppChannelException, UnrecoverablePduException, InterruptedException {
        PduResponse pdu = dlrs.remove(dlrId);
        if (pdu != null) {
            pdu.setResultMessage("0xa");
            sendResponsePdu(pdu);
        }
    }
```

i look for a way to return on method sendResponsePdu the SMPP error code in case of an error

i expect to see in client the error code 0xa
which means "Invalid source address"
but get as usual ESME_ROK
i toke image from C# project where i can see how the response should look like
when send from SMSC
[image]

**UPDATE**
i used the next code to return the DLR, but i can't find a way to set the "err","stat" and messageid
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25885741/9698435)

Answer (score 0):

this is the solution to set all DLR fields and send it back to the client

```
 byte[] textBytes = "-".getBytes();

        DeliverSm deliver = new DeliverSm();

        deliver.setSourceAddress(new Address((byte) 0x03, (byte) 0x00, pduResponseWrapper.getFromNumber()));
        deliver.setDestAddress(new Address((byte) 0x01, (byte) 0x01, pduResponseWrapper.getToNumber()));
        deliver.setShortMessage(textBytes);
        deliver.setDataCoding(pduResponseWrapper.getDataCoding());
        deliver.setSequenceNumber(pduResponseWrapper.getDeliverSm().getSequenceNumber());
        deliver.setEsmClass((byte) 0x04);
        deliver.setProtocolId((byte) 0x00);
        deliver.setPriority((byte) 0x00);
        deliver.setScheduleDeliveryTime(null);
        deliver.setValidityPeriod(null);
        deliver.setRegisteredDelivery((byte) 0x00);
        deliver.setReplaceIfPresent((byte) 0x00);
        deliver.setDefaultMsgId((byte) 0x00);

        DateTime submitDate = new DateTime();
        DateTime doneDate = new DateTime();
        byte state=SmppConstants.STATE_DELIVERED;
        String errorCode="000";
        DeliveryReceipt deliveryReceipt = new DeliveryReceipt(dlrId, 1,
                1, submitDate, doneDate,
                state, errorCode, "");



        String shortMessage = deliveryReceipt.toShortMessage();
        deliver.setShortMessage(CharsetUtil.encode(shortMessage, CharsetUtil.CHARSET_GSM));  deliver.calculateAndSetCommandLength();



        DataSmResp dd=new DataSmResp();
        DeliveryReceipt deliveryReceipt=new DeliveryReceipt();
        DeliverSmResp deliverSmResp = new DeliverSmResp();*/


        WindowFuture<Integer, PduRequest, PduResponse> future = session.sendRequestPdu(deliver, 10000, false);
        if (!future.await()) {
            logger.error("Failed to receive deliver_sm_resp within specified time");
        } else if (future.isSuccess()) {
            DeliverSmResp deliverSmResp = (DeliverSmResp) future.getResponse();
            logger.info("deliver_sm_resp: commandStatus [" + deliverSmResp.getCommandStatus() + "=" + deliverSmResp.getResultMessage() + "]");
        } else {
            logger.error("Failed to properly receive deliver_sm_resp: " + future.getCause());
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
```